# Nested form is not showing up!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a nested model structure that looks like this:

```
resources :users, :path => '/' do
    resources :accounts do
        resources :characters
    end
end
```

I'm trying to get the `accounts#new` page to show both the forms but for some reason only the accounts form is displayed ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPJJq.png)).

Here's the git: https://github.com/imjp/d2shed

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :account_name, :realm
accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters

belongs_to :user
has_many :characters, :dependent => :destroy 

validates :account_name, :presence => 'true',
                    :length => { :in => 4..20 },
                    :uniqueness => 'true'

validates_presence_of :realm
validates_format_of :account_name, :with => /^[A-Za-z\d_]+$/
end
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
def new 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @account = Account.new
    @account.characters.build
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@user, @account]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :account_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :account_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.radio_button(:realm, "USWest") %>
    <%= f.label(:realm, "USWest") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:realm, "USEast") %>
    <%= f.label(:realm, "USEast") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:realm, "Europe") %>
    <%= f.label(:realm, "Europe") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:realm, "Asia") %>
    <%= f.label(:realm, "Asia") %>
 </div>     

<%= f.fields_for :character do |character_form| %>

        <div class="field"> 
            Name: <%= character_form.text_field :name %>
        </div> 
    <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:** The code works now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you doing `fields_for ".."` ?

What you want to do is `<%= f.fields_for :characters %>` as that will iterate through all the characters and render the fields as required in the account form. By calling `fields_for` on the `f` object you're telling the parent form that it contains nested attributes.

Secondly, you'll need to use the `@account` object in your form rather than building another one with `@user.accounts.build`. By doing it this wrong way, you're actually creating a new account object which wouldn't have any character objects pre-built for it.

In addition to this you will need to specify `accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters` in your `Account` model so that the form accepts them along with the account parameters.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! I modified the code but it's still not working :/  I've edited my question to update the code as well. Can you take a look what else might be missing?

Comment: @imjp: If you clarified what's "still not working" then perhaps yes.

Comment: @imjp: Actually I noticed you made a mistake in your form. Middle paragraph in my answer fixes that mistake.

Comment: By still not working I mean that the `users/:id/accounts/new` page still isn't displaying the form for `characters`. I fixed the form code you told me about in the middle paragraph but for some reason the form for `characters` still isn't showing.. hmm

Comment: If fixed the problem! I should've put `<%=` instead of `<%` for the `f.fields_for` line!

Comment: @imjp Its funny how funny i feel about thanking you for pointing out such a stupid mistake i also made. <%= displays the nested records. Thanks

Comment: Man, that <%= was what was missing on my program as well! I was going around this for 2 hours! Thanks!

Comment: Adding @user.accounts.build on the controller worked for me.

Comment: I think that `build` action is needed too?